# AlarmManager not working when app is closed even receiver is set in manifest

Tags: java, android

Test: sdk 19
My manifest

```
<receiver android:name=".pushnotification.TimeAlarm"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

I set up alarm manager

```
private void setAlarm(String portionName, String orderId, int time, int requestCode) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, TimeAlarm.class);
        intent.putExtra(TimeAlarm.PORTION_NAME, portionName);
        intent.putExtra(MainScreenActivity.ORDER_ID, orderId);
        intent.putExtra(ALARM_REQUEST_KEY, requestCode);
        int id = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, id, intent, FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + time, pendingIntent);
    }
```

This is my receiver

```
public class TimeAlarm extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public static final String PORTION_NAME = "portionName";
    private NotificationManager mNotifyMgr;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        int notificationId = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();
        //Do something here

    }
}
```

I have tried a lot of solutions and I can see nothing wrong with my code. But the receiver cannot receive alarm broadcast when the app is closed. When the app is paused, it works ok

Comment: Refer to [link](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/nougat/android-7.0-changes.html)

Comment: is this tested on an htc device?

Comment: UMI ZERO phone. Sdk 19

Answer (score 0):

You should also register for this intent

`<action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />`

Comment: in the manifest after `<action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />`

Comment: I test the code on Samsung devices and my code works perfectly

Comment: @trnahaminh then this is an issue specific to umi zero?